# value/strings.xml vs. layout/*.xml

Tags: android, layout

Can anybody enlighten me why `value/strings.xml` is useful(important)?

It occurred to me that all the `attributes`, e.g., id, label can be set in the layout xml as well. So why `strings.xml`?

A side question is, once get an ID of an object, say a `listitem`, how do I get the android:text from it?

I did not find any `getText()` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It allows for easily providing alternate languages and configurations. See the [Resources and Internationalization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html) topic (especially the Alternate Resources section) in the Dev Guide for more information.

For your second question, you may be looking for `resolveInfo.nonLocalizedLabel` or `resolveInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())`?

The reference page for [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) should help you find what you want.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your 2nd question, you can use `findViewById(...)` in your Activity to get the View class.

From the View class you can call `getText()`.

To access views of list items in a ListView, override the `getView()` method in your adapter.

For example:

```
new SimpleAdapter(Activity.this, model, R.layout.my_layout, from, to) {

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View myView = findById(R.id.my_id); //< Access your view here!

        return view;
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second question:

If your id is `R.id.editText1`, then you need to get the EditText control first,

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Then you can call the `getText()` method.

```
editText1.getText();
```

Comment: Same comment as I left for Mayra's answer, how might this work for a ListItem?